# Data from a table in 1 DB needed for filter in different DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, filtering, merge-replication

I have a Win Form, Data Entry, application that uses 4 seperate Data Bases.  This is an occasionally connected app that uses Merge Replication (*SQL 2005*) to stay in Sync.  This is working just fine.  The next hurdle I am trying to tackle is adding Filters to my Publications.

Right now we are replicating 70mbs, compressed, to each of our 150 subscribers when, truthfully, they only need a tiny fraction of that.  Using Filters I am able to accomplish this(see code below) but I had to make a mapping table in order to do so.  This mapping table consists of 3 columns.  A PrimaryID(Guid), WorkerName(varchar), and ClientID(int).

The problem is I need this table present in all FOUR Databases in order to use it for the filter since, to my knowledge, views or cross-db query's are not allowed in a Filter Statement.

What are my options?

Seems like I would set it up to be maintained in 1 Database and then use Triggers to keep it updated in the other 3 Databases.  In order to be a part of the Filter I have to include that table in the Replication Set so how do I flag it appropriately.

Is there a better way, altogether?

```
SELECT <published_columns> FROM [dbo].[tblPlan] WHERE [ClientID] IN (select ClientID from [dbo].[tblWorkerOwnership] where WorkerID = SUSER_SNAME())
```

Which allows you to chain together Filters, this next one is below the first one so it only pulls from the first's Filtered Set.

```
SELECT <published_columns> FROM [dbo].[tblPlan] INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblHealthAssessmentReview] ON [tblPlan].[PlanID] = [tblHealthAssessmentReview].[PlanID]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced/designingcrossdatabasequeries/1753/

You are able to use cross DB queries in views.

Comment: `**views** or cross-db query's are not allowed in a Filter Statement.`  Thanks for the response but I already knew that and that is, also, not my question.  See quoted...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how quicky you need this filter data 'replicated' on the servers, you could create a job on the slave servers that updated the tables with data from the primary server. You wouldn't get updates right away like you would with triggers, but I think the design would be cleaner.

E.g. cross database queries executed as jobs on the server, that do a simple

```
 DELETE FROM filterTable
```

and then

```
 INSERT INTO filterTable ....
```

to refresh the table used in the filters at a schedule you select.

Comment: thank you for the idea.  All my DB's are on the same server instance I just need data from one DB for the Filter on the others